# Test for text content in XSLT when trying to insert blank lines

Tags: html, xslt, xsl-fo

A while ago I asked this question: [using xslt stylesheet to convert xhtml blank lines to an XSL-FO blank line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327957/using-xslt-stylesheet-to-convert-xhtml-blank-lines-to-an-xsl-fo-blank-line)

However, I now have a similar issue that the fix that was suggested there will not work for.

The previous solution looked like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="html:br[following-sibling::*[1][self::html:br]]">
    <fo:block space-after="1em">
      <xsl:call-template name="process-common-attributes"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="html:br[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::html:br]]" />

  <xsl:template match="html:br">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:call-template name="process-common-attributes"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
```

but I now have a piece of html looking like this:

```
<p>text<br />text<br />text<br /><br /><br />text</p>
```

The difference with the previous post is that here I do not have elements for the text (like span) but am simply alternating pieces of text and br elements. This will incorrectly give positives for all br's in my example. Unfortunately I do not have control over the input HTML.

The ideal solution that I can come up with would be to insert the fo:block with 1em height only when there was no text between the next br and this one. Does anyone know either how to achieve this or a better solution for this problem (I do not want to replace all br tags with \n and set linefeed-treatment to preserve as this will open a whole new can of worms)

**Edit:** the desired output would be this:

```
text
text
text


text
```

So it should preserve (multiple) linebreaks but not add additional white lines after single `<br>`'s.

How this could look like in XSL-FO is this (with the initial block with space-before and space-after coming from the transformation of the <p> element)

```
                <fo:block space-after="1em" space-before="1em">text
                  <fo:block/>text
                  <fo:block/>text
                  <fo:block space-after="1em"/>
                  <fo:block space-after="1em"/>
                  <fo:block/>text
                </fo:block>
```

I'm open to suggestions though.

Comment: There are many solutions. What would be the exact desired output for your imput sample?

Comment: By "exact" I meant with XSL-FO markup.

Comment: I added a possible XSL-FO solution but this is not set in stone and I'm happy to consider alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <fo:block space-after="1em" space-before="1em">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="br[following-sibling::node()[1]/self::br]">
        <fo:block space-after="1em"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="br">
        <fo:block/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<fo:block space-after="1em" space-before="1em"
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">text
    <fo:block />text
    <fo:block />text
    <fo:block space-after="1em" />
    <fo:block space-after="1em" />
    <fo:block />text
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Nice, this works, thank you! I need to read a book about these features.

Comment: @Bas van den Broek: The difference is that `br[following-sibling::*[1][self::br]]">` test against first following-sibling **element** thus not taking text nodes, comments nor PI into acount.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What does PI stand for?

Comment: @Bas van den Broek: [Processing Instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-pi)